# Dúvida DataGridView em C#

Tags: c#

Eu gostaria de saber o que é e para que são usado estes tipos de códigos:

```
txtCodigo.Text = dtgProfessores.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CODIGO"].Value.ToString();
txtNome.Text = dtgProfessores.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NOME"].Value.ToString();
txtEndereco.Text = dtgProfessores.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ENDERECO"].Value.ToString();
txtBairro.Text = dtgProfessores.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["BAIRRO"].Value.ToString();
txtCidade.Text = dtgProfessores.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CIDADE"].Value.ToString();
```

Eu gostaria de uma explicação clara e simples. Desde já muito obrigado :)

Comment: Provavelmente são usados para a edição de conteúdo ao selecionar uma linha do GridView dtgProfessores, Ou apenas exibilos em um outro contexto.

Comment: Temos um `DataGridView`, pegando a CELULA `["CODIGO"]` convertendo seu valor para String e atribuindo ao `txtCodigo.Text` e assim por diante...

Answer (score 0):

O mesmo vale para todos portando vou explicar só o primeiro! 
Ele pega do Componente `DataGridView`, o elemento na linha `e.RowIndex`, a coluna "`Codigo`" e nesta coluna o valor que está la dentro ai ele converte usando `.toString()` o valor la dentro para String, e depois coloca dentro do `txtCodigo.text`.